# Why did Chromecast stop working on my Android?

Tags: chromecast

I have a Samsung Galaxy Note 10 Plus smartphone and recently I stopped being able to cast anything to my TV nor my speakers, whether YouTube or Hulu or even just sound/music apps like Spotify. It seems I can't connect to either Chromecast video nor audio devices. The devices I can cast to at home do appear on my list of possible casting destinations, but then the content won't display. The attempt to connect from my phone seems to fail every time! Other people at home are able to cast fine. I have already also tried wiping the cache and data storage on the Google Home, Android System Webview, Chrome, and YouTube apps. No improvement!

Answer (score 0):

Somehow I remembered that I had recently turned on my Avast VPN. It never turned itself back off! The VPN connection seems to prevent my phone from casting audio and video to my home devices. Turning my VPN off manually on the phone corrected the problem!

Answer (score 0):

Checking for VPNs or other networking issues could help, it's usually something silly that gets in the way but occasionally they are unrecoverable but it's rare.

Try using it on a direct connection if possible.

Good luck!

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).